# Switch statement works with backspace KeyCode, if statement does not?

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, switch-statement, keycode

I always thought the if & switch statements basically compared things the same way but in different formats. However, when I was trying to capture the backspace keycode the switch is the only one that picked up on a comparison. Why is this?

https://jsfiddle.net/ogbw8g8u/3/

```
$(window).on('keydown', function (e) {
e.preventDefault();

  if( e.KeyCode == 8 ) {
    $('div').append('<p>if</p>');
  }

  switch (e.keyCode) {
    case 8: // Backspace
      $('div').append('<p>switch</p>');
      break;
  }

});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error you have is not the statement, it is the capitalization. Your if statement should not have the `k` in `keyCode` capitalized. It should be:

```
if (e.keyCode == 8) {
    ...
}
```